# react mapping function not working

Tags: reactjs, mapping

hey all i have this array of objects

```
this.state = {
        users :[{
            userid:'1',
            fullName :'eddyabikhalil',
            dob:'10/03/1994',
            gender:'M',
            loan:[{
                loanid:'1',
                date:'20/7/2012',
                loanValue:'100$',
            }, 

            {
                loanid:'2',
                date:'21/4/2014',
                loanValue:'200$',
            },

            {
                loanid:'3',
                date:'20/12/2015',
                loanValue:'300$',
            }]
    },




 userid:'2',
 fullName :'joe salloum',
 dob:'11/04/1993',
 gender:'M',
loan:[{
loanid:'4',
date:'20/7/2012',
loanValue:'500$',
}, 

 {
loanid:'5',
date:'21/4/2017',
loanValue:'600$',
 },

{
loanid:'6',
date:'20/12/2012',
loanValue:'700$',
}

  ],

    }]
}



 }
```

so i wrote this function to map inside of this array of object:

```
renderTable(userValue) {
let HTML = [];
let groupedVals = groupBy(userValue, 'userid');
let usersObj = [];

map(groupedVals, (value,  key) => {

    let userss = {
       FullName: value.fullName,
        dob: value.dob,
        gender: value.gender,
        loans: []
    }

    map(value, (subValue) => {                
        userss.loans.push(subValue.loanValue)
    })

    usersObj.push(userss);




})


map(usersObj, (val) => {

    HTML.push(<tr>
        <td>
            {val.FullName}
        </td>

        <td>
            {val.dob}
        </td>

         <td>
            {val.gender}
        </td>

        <td>
            {val.loans.join(',')}
        </td>
      </tr>
        )
        })


 return HTML;
  }
```

i want to make a table with the following fields: fullName, dob, gender and loan

i want to show that `userid = 1` have multiple loan value in one `td`

so i created this table:

```
render() {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>FullName</td>
                    <td>dob</td>
                    <td>gender</td>
                    <td>loans</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    this.state.users &&
                    this.renderTable(this.state.users)
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);
```

}

any help guys? thanks in advance

Comment: Can you format your code and indent it properly, please?

Comment: map is  not used like that. use on array

Comment: how? can you help me plz how to do it? @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Answer (score 0):

```
render() {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <table className="table table-striped">

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>FullName</td>
                    <td>dob</td>
                    <td>gender</td>
                    <td>loans</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {
                    this.state.users.map((user) => (
                        <tr>
                             <td>{user.fullName}</td>
                             <td>{user.dob}</td>
                             <td>{user.gender}</td>
                             <td>{user.loan.map((loan) => { return (loan.id + ",") })}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: it returns am empty table

Comment: this will work just check your data and everything. I updated it please check replaced curly braces with small braces

Comment: ok thank you but a small problem.. it only returns one person but here i have two... im sorry if im bothering you

Comment: can you see two users in console as console.log(this.state.users)

Comment: as you posted in the question your state doesnot seems to be correctly formatted. I have formatted the first user please format your second user like that

Comment: i need to have the sum of loans per each user? can anyone help me